# When I read a binary file, its size is wrong

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, binary

I want to read a binary data that has 518*723 array with uint32.
In matlab, I read the data without any problem using 'fread'.
Data size is correct '374514'.

But, in python ( I use the pycharm, Windows10), I got wrong data size.

```
>> n_data = np.fromfile(data, dtype = 'uint32') 
>> n_data.reshape(1,518,723)    
>> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 723000 into shape (1,518,723)
>> n_data.size
>> 723000
```

'data' is the file name. The size of file is 1,048,576 byte in Windows 10 OS.

in matlab:

```
>> a = fopen(data)
>> b = fread(a, 723*518, 'uint32')
>> size(b) 
>> 374514
```

Why did the result show differently? How can I reshape the array of n_data to 518*723??

Comment: Is `data` a string holding the file name, or an open file object?

Comment: What is the size of the file on disk?

Comment: What's the matlab `fread` command?

Comment: Do the numbers look the same

Comment: You are not checking the file size, you are checking the size of data in memory. Take note that it is conveniently roughly twice the size of your file - which is common for overallocating vectors.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I found that the data is right values from (0,0) to (512, 722). Remained data(row:513~) may be overallocating vectors. How can I read the data without overallocating vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the it might have something to do with the way numpy and Matlab represent/understand what data size represents.

If you check the [numpy.fromfile documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) it has a note on data storage that we could stretch to what you are describing:

> Do not rely on the combination of tofile and fromfile for data storage, as the binary files generated are are not platform independent. In particular, no byte-order or data-type information is saved. Data can be stored in the platform independent .npy format using save and load instead.